# html form without action, without submit and no javascript

Tags: html, forms

What purpose would a form server that did not have an action ,, 
nor did it have a submit or button, and no javascript anywhere on the page..

```
               <form method="post">
               <input type="hidden" name="dtsg" value="AQAdsMJX" autocomplete="off" />
               <i class="imgprofpic">
               <img src="http://abc.com/img.jpg" class="imgCrop img"  />
               </i>
               <a href="/test">
               test
               </a>
               <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="page" value="0" />
               <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="last_page" value="0" />
               </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no (external) javascript at all?

Comment: yes there absolutely no javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would use it for css
    `<style>
    form{
    border:1px solid gray;
    }
    </style>`

Still serves a purpose

Answer (score 0):

It may be designed to be read into another page by an ajax call in which the JS would exist on the reading page.

Comment: Ok , this sounds possible.. However, why would it be on a visible page ? .

Comment: The page in question is a result from ( http://m.facebook.com/search/?query=aa&search=object&ssid=1611839595&s=2&refid=46 )

Comment: The page I get at that link has scripts all over it. And the form has actions, I see nothing like the example in your question.

Comment: are you sure you went to m.facebook.com and not www.facebook.com ?

Comment: yup, though they may have some redirection based on user agent. What user agent are you navigating there with?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0